# Will JHister support DB2 in future releases or there is anyway to connect DB2 from JHipster?

Tags: db2, jhipster

Will JHister support DB2 in future releases or there is anyway to establish connection to DB2 from JHipster?

Answer (score 0):

No planned support for DB2.

To support it you must generate for another database, modify settings in application*.yml (spring.datasource.*) and check that Liquibase changesets work.

Comment: Thanks for reply..I will check by modifying and try my luck.